# How to use Threading using python tkinter program?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog


# initialize gui interface
root=Tk()
root.geometry("510x200")

global folder_selected, path

def getFolderPath():

      # do somthing

btnFind = ttk.Button(root, text="Browse Folder",command=getFolderPath)


def down():     

        #do somthing


dwn=ttk.Button(root,text="Download",width='25',command=down)
dwn.place(x=190,y=120)

root.mainloop()
```

Here in this program I want to use threading. I do not know about threading how can I implement threading in this program using Python.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `threading` module. I have written a little code fro you. The `background` function can start your function on separated threads.

If your function has input parameter, you can pass them like: `command=lambda : background(print_numbers, (50,)))`. Important: `args` must be a tuple even if it is only one

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("510x200")


def getFolderPath():
    print("getFolderPath. Thread: {}".format(threading.get_ident()))
    time.sleep(10)


def down():
    print("Down. Thread: {}".format(threading.get_ident()))


def background(func, args):
    th = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args)
    th.start()


btnFind = ttk.Button(root, text="Browse Folder", command=lambda: background(getFolderPath, ()))
btnFind.place(x=0, y=0)

dwn = ttk.Button(root, text="Download", width="25", command=lambda: background(down, ()))
dwn.place(x=190, y=120)


root.mainloop()
```

**The getting window:**

[image: getting window]

**The console output:** (if you click the buttons)

```
>>> python3test_file.py 
Down. Thread: 140212479096576
Down. Thread: 140212479096576
getFolderPath. Thread: 140212479096576
getFolderPath. Thread: 140212468516608
getFolderPath. Thread: 140212460123904
Down. Thread: 140212451731200
getFolderPath. Thread: 140212451731200
Down. Thread: 140212443338496
```

You can see the ID of thread are different. It means the tasks were running on different threads.